# Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (8:26)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to display a text box in react.
- but I am getting an error.
  Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (8:26)
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing it below.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/3/

```or-tag-here
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
                    <textarea value = this.state.value>
                        there should be only 140 characters
                </textarea>
    </div>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of an attribute must be an expression {foo} or quoted text "foo"

use this line

```
<textarea value = {this.state.value}>
```

instead of

```
<textarea value = this.state.value>
```

example:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
getInitialState() {
    return { value:"hello"};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
                    <textarea value = {this.state.value}>
                        there should be only 140 characters
                </textarea>
    </div>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwu28tx4/